# How can I style a class that is an expression using modules

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am creating a component in my react app however, I don't want to use global styling, but modules. The problem is that one of the classNames is an expression, how do I style it in with modules. Below is my code.

```
       <div className="container">
           <div className={`current image ${move}`}>
               {images[this.state.index]} 
           </div>
           <div className={`next image ${move}`}>
               {images[this.state.next]} 
           </div>
      </div>
```

how do I convert the expression `` <div className={`current image ${move}`}> `` to be styled in module.

for example, in modules `<div className="container">` will be `<div className={style.container}>`.

thanks.

Comment: Answer below seems good. There's also a package named `classnames` which could be useful for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer to your question, to solve the above all you have to do is to concatenate the classnames into a single string, almost as you have done.

It can look something like this:

```
<div className={[style.next, style.image, style.move].join(" ")}>content...</div>
```

Here we simply construct an array of the module classnames and then join it together with a space as a separator.

---

If you however want some classes to be conditional, i recommend the npm package [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames). Then it could look something like this instead:

```
<div className={classNames(style.image, {
  [style.current]: isCurrent,
  [style.move]: isMoving
)}>
```

given that `isCurrent` and `isMoving` is declared `boolean` somewhere above this snippet.

Comment: Thank you, code worked as it rendered my image, however, the ${move} expression did not give the desired outcome, how can I fix this.

Comment: @Raphael that depends what `move` is? is it the classname from the css file or is it a boolean?